# Use a single font for equation labels

Tags: fonts, cross-referencing, babel

I use Latex with `babel` to write Hebrew documents. I have different fonts for Hebrew and English and there is a weird consequence to that. Take a look at this sample code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, layout=tabular]{babel}

\babelprovide[main, import, alph=letters, Alph=letters]{hebrew}
\babelprovide[import]{english}

\babelfont{rm}{TeX Gyre Bonum}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Arial}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
עוצמת הגל כפונקציה של הזווית נתונה על ידי
\begin{equation}\label{eq:intensity}
    I = I_0 \cos^2 \theta
\end{equation}

לפי משוואה \eqref{eq:intensity} וגם \eqref{eq:intensity2}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:intensity2}
    I = I_0 \cos^2 \theta
\end{equation}

According to equation \eqref{eq:intensity2} and \eqref{eq:intensity}
\end{document}
```

When compiling this code with LuaLatex, I get the following result:
[image]

As you can see when I work in Hebrew the labels of equations use the Hebrew font `Arial` and when I switch to English, it uses the English font `TeX Gyre Bonum` (I changed the English font so it will be different than the math font). This creates an annoying inconsistency in the document: Math is typeset using its own font, but the labels use different fonts depending on the language I happen to be using right now.

How can I configure `babel` to use the math font for equation labeling regardless of the selected language? Also, can I configure a specific font for the labels? (The English font or the Hebrew font or maybe an entirely different font, but the important thing is it's the same font for all labels)

I don't know if I should enforce the same font for the *referencing* of equations as well, or if it's preferred to keep the references the way they are, so they match the current language. I'd like to know what is more correct for a serious article (in university, for example), and if I should maintain the same font in references too, then how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

`amsmath` doesn’t provide a ‘user’ macro to redefine the tag format, but its manual explains what internal macro can be used for this purpose (`\maketag@@@`). With:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\maketag@@@}[1]{%
  \hbox{\m@th\normalfont\foreignlanguage{hebrew}{\mbox{#1}}}}%
\makeatother
```

I get:
[image]